# Chrome toolbar icons acting weirdly

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It recently started happening that the icons in Google Chrome started freaking out, and randomly look weird:

[image: first screenshot]

And they don't always look the same, either:

[image: second screenshot]

The appearance of them tends to change if I hover over them, do any tab-related actions, disconnect or connect my external monitor, etc.

The download circle progress bar and icon also exhibit this behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using the dev version of Chrome (19.0.1077.3). If so, this is a bug that was introduced a few days ago. Expect it to be fixed with the new update. Here's the bug report on the official Google blog: [Dev Channel Update](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2012/03/dev-channel-update_23.html).

Edit: I just checked for updates manually, and indeed the update was available, solving the rendering issue. To get the update now, got to Chrome settings (`chrome://chrome/settings/`), and click on the `Help` tab. The app will check for updates automatically, and ask you to relaunch the browser.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I am using the dev version of chrome. Glad it will be fixed soon, I've tried deleting my profile, chrome preferences, etc. Green check for you (in 6 minutes)

Comment: Added an edit - it seems to be all fixed already.

Comment: Relaunched and it's fixed!